# Error loading Visual Studio 2012 and 2015 projects

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

I have been with VS2012 for a few years now. I developed my first asp.net/angularjs project under VS2012. 
Secondly, I recently checked out a VS2013 project (written by a 3rd party) which ran just fine under 2012.

Then it was suggested that I install VS2015 on my laptop. This is when things went wrong.

**Problems**:
I attempted to load the new VS2013 project in VS2015, but it immediately failed to load.

***VS2015 error:***

```
Creation of the virtual directory http://localhost:32999/ 
failed with the error: Filename: redirection.config
Error: Cannot read configuration file
```

Now when I go back to ***VS2012*** and load my original asp.net/angular project, I get this error:

[image: Error loading vs2012 project]

So in the end, I can't load any projects at all ! Neither 2012 nor 2015.

My local IIS websites are still running fine, by the way, but not the local dev environments.

How can I fix these virtual directories ?

Thanks in advance,
Bob

Comment: I found that this error was caused by my project being on a share drive under a virtual machine. Copying the project to the local C drive and opening resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As per some guidance from this post - [IISExpress 8 Cannot read configuration file redirection.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15897726/iisexpress-8-cannot-read-configuration-file-redirection-config), here's how I got my VS2015 to load up successfully:

- Close VS2015
- Go into folder %userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress\config
- Rename applicationhost.config
- Restart VS and load the solution/project
- VS should have recreated applicationhost.config, and project should load

Of course, I now have a different error, which I will post anew:

```
[BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyWebApp.DAL' 
or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made 
to load a program with an incorrect format.]
```

Comment: I think `BadImageFormatException` is specific to the user. Deleting the applicationhost config file from this location solved my issue.

Answer (score 4):

I resolved the same problem by starting visual studio with Administrator rights. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727454/what-is-this-vague-error-with-redirection-config-while-building-a-web-deploy-p) pointed me in the right direction and gives more solutions.

Answer (score 3):

This may be due to checked-in applicationhost file.
Delete the file from the repository. Build the project again. This file will be created automatically. Don't check in this config file again.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work for everyone, but in my case, the file that couldn't be written was actually a temp file in C:\users\\AppData\Local\Temp\iisexpress. We were getting a company wide virus attack and they shut this area down for everyone. They were able to change the policy just for me and that fixed it.